# Insult: something smells

Tags: usage

On [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz_IwJD_yn8) YouTube video, the author claims that one way to insult someone is the following:

[image]

Is that true? The author seemed to be honest enough. How does that make sense? (Note that I actually know nothing about Japanese)

Comment: The guy in the video is not teaching you the right things. Ignore him and find something better to watch.

Comment: Not to be rude, but without elaborating, your comment has given me exactly zero information.

Comment: Clearly, the author is not teaching Japanese honestly. If you don't want to learn Japanese and simply want to watch the video as an overly exaggerated ethnic joke, that's fine, but don't expect to get anything serious out of his video.

Comment: The first one mentioned in this video is なんかアニメ好きそうな見た目してますね. No joke. Right before I got on JSE and saw this post, a stranger I met online literally said エロ漫画が好きそうですね to me and meant it as a rude joke.

Answer (score 3):

I took it as "what's this strange smell? - (staring at someone) - oh that explains it". It basically says "you stink" with more words.

Answer (score 3):

1. He explains it himself in the video.
2. The entire video is basically comedy / a shitpost. Although these expressions might be insulting in some situations, they are not as generically useful as F U is in English. He probably selected them because they make for amusing skits.

Answer (score 2):

That expression can be counted as one of a million possible creative ways of jokingly insulting someone in an anime, but it is not a useful expression worth memorizing as a set phrase. To be clear, it's not an equivalent of f**k. The "example" he is showing in the video is basically just a surreal comedy skit. To me, it's far from realistic.

It appears to me that the author is using his language skill to make fun of Japanese and amuse English speakers. Judging from the number of likes and comments written in English, his attempt may have been successful, but I wonder how many of them understand the Japanese language. Almost everything I could found in his top videos are exaggerated ethnic jokes. If you ever study Japanese in the future, please don't take anything seriously in his video.

Comment: I got the opposite impression. The targeted audience seems to be Japanese people who have had experience with foreign Japanese learners. I often hear young Japanese people talk about how ridiculous the Japanese of Japanese learners sounds, especially if they picked it up from anime. A learner has to have some cultural understanding of this phenomenon and how the weeb community is perceived by Japanese young people to appreciate his humor which is actually a pretty high bar, both culturally and linguistically. Was gonna write an answer discussing this but thought it was somewhat off-topic.

Comment: @EddieKal Ah, he may be also poking fun of so-called weeaboos in some videos, but the targeted audience of the videos I've seen so far is English speakers (e.g., [this](https://youtu.be/sLK7DP8-B-I)). That's why almost all comments are written in English. (And of course he has exaggerated a rare exceptional experience in this video... Most Japanese speakers know how American English sounds like.)

Comment: @Eddie Kal I don't think it would be off topic...rather spot-on. Sure he is making funny videos, but based on existent concepts. I do not think he would generate things out of thin air to ridicule them later.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I totally agree. That would have been one of my core points. I ditched my 80% done answer which said the clip, like all comedy, was based on the content creator's personal experience and observations. Anyways, I don't think I want to repeat that effort. Also my answer would have talked mostly about the #1&3 in the video, as opposed to #2 which you are asking about here.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis His videos may look honest and real to non-Japanese, but they are overexaggerated and fundamentally fake to my eyes. In the video I linked, he says "this is PARTIALLY based on a real story", which won't be a lie if only a small portion of a video is related to some fact. "Based on existent concepts" is not an excuse. Imagine how you feel if Japanese people enjoy a video of a "typical American" wearing a cowboy hat and happily shooting people with a rifle while eating pizza and speaking like Terminator.